# How do I correctly execute 'vim $(grep -rli pattern | sed 's/\(.*\)/"&"/')' in bash?

Tags: bash, vim, grep, sed, filenames

I am trying to edit files that contain text matching a regular expression with vim and use the following command in bash to do that:

```
vim $(grep -rli pattern | sed 's/\(.*\)/"&"/')
```

I pipe the output of the `grep` command into `sed` to qutoe file names with spaces. However, it does not work: file names that contain spaces are not opened by vim with this command.

This puzzles me because when I execute

```
echo $(grep -rli pattern | sed 's/\(.*\)/"&"/')
```

the file names are properly quoted.

So, what do I have to change to make vim open files with spaces?

Comment: "when I execute `echo …` the file names are properly quoted" – Quotes coming from the expansion of `$()` are not special to the shell. Get familiar with `xargs`.

Comment: See ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system call that starts a new process takes a list of strings like this:

1. `vim`
2. `/path/to/file`
3. `./path to a file with spaces/foo`
4. …

Note there are no quotes around the 3rd item - these strings are already itemized and the system will pass it to vim as a whole.

The quotes are not for vim or for the OS. They are for the shell, because you're entering commands as a single string. The shell will then have to split it into items, so it needs to know which spaces are item separators and which are parts of an item.

`$(…)` is expanded after quotes are already evaluated and produces different items: instead of `vim`, `file name` you're getting `vim`, `"file`, `name"`, with quotes inside the items but space treated as a separator.

These "items" are actually called *arguments*, by the way.

The solution is to use `xargs`: a program that takes lines from the standard input and appends them as arguments to a given command.

```
grep -rli pattern | sed 's/\(.*\)/"&"/' | xargs vim
```